# Why are some cultures historically more modest than others?

Tags: religion, cultural-history

Ancient Greeks, for example, were obviously very comfortable with nudity, as reflected in a lot of their art. On the other hand, Islamic cultures value modesty much more. And of course there are countless other cultures that range in between.

Why does this happen? One of my guesses would be temperatures, that if it's warmer in a place they would be more comfortable wearing less clothing, but isn't it warmer in the middle east than in Greece?

Another factor that I thought about was religion, as Greek mythology was often more crude than the Islamic stories. But are the cultures more modest because their stories are more modest or is it vice versa? Are there other factors that weigh in that I didn't mention?

I suppose by "modesty" I mean the extent that the culture is comfortable with exposed bodies. Greeks, for example, made plenty of statues and pieces of art of naked people, but Islamic cultures emphasize more modest, concealing clothing and dress.

I chose the examples of Greek and Islamic cultures because they were the first ones that came to mind. Sorry if I said something incorrect. I'm very curious about this topic and eager to hear what you have to say.

Comment: What do "modest" and "modesty" mean in this context?

Comment: Welcome to History:Stack Exchange. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Comment: This is a question from a new user, who may not be familiar with our [culture](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4053/faq-historystack-exchange) on H:SE. Please make an extra effort to be welcoming: phrase feedback in a positive manner and try to explain our assumptions. If possible, offer constructive advice on how to [improve the question](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3224).

Comment: The explanation of these differences lies in the religion. It is religion which imposes on people this notion of "modesty".

Comment: I'm not sure that's true.  I don't see lots of naked atheists wander around.

Comment: I think if you take civilizations from the same time period it could be an interesting question. But Greek Mythology (1800BCE) and Islam(610CE) lie too far apart.

Comment: @Gort the Robot: At least in the US, that's because the mostly-Christian majority has enacted laws against public nudity.  I dare say if you did a religious survey at a nude beach, you would find many atheists & agnostics (and pagans &c), and few conservative Christians :-)

Comment: I'm very skeptical of any theory that is based on two examples, particularly two who are so different in time, climate and economy.   I seem to recall that modesty is connected to the need to establish paternity, which is inversely related to fecundity/child survival rates, but I don't remember enough of the context.  Ultimately, I think more research is needed including the analysis of more examples.

Comment: Note that the title is really confusing, because to most native English speakers, the primary meanings of "modest" have nothing to do with covering parts of the body: https://www.dictionary.com/browse/modest  "Body modesty" might work...

Comment: My Professional Historian Girlfriend points out that body modesty is relative - measured in the context of your own.  I'd suggest that Japanese culture be included in the mix - where the "immodest" areas are different than our own.

Comment: reopen vote would be easier to support if the question addressed the issues raised.

Answer (score -1):

This is completely hypothetical and quite a bit of guesswork, but around the world you can find examples how fashion or beauty ideals are derived from the lifestyles of the elites. E.g. sun tanning in pre- or post-industrialization Europe or in China, [foot binding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foot_binding) in China, changing ideals re. body figures etc.

In most cultures, nakedness (esp. partial male nakedness) will be associated with hard work, which automatically counts against it (e.g. [Ancient Rome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slavery_in_ancient_Rome#/media/File:Roman_mosaic_describing_slaves_performing_agricultural_tasks.jpg), [European middle ages](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/History_of_agricultural_illustration#/media/File:Battage_%C3%A0_fl%C3%A9au_(original).jpg), [19th century Japan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fifty-three_Stations_of_the_T%C5%8Dkaid%C5%8D#/media/File:Hiroshige23_fujieda.jpg), [socialist propaganda](https://www.geschichte.sachsen.de/adolf-hennecke-5710.html?_pp=%7B%7D)). Greece was somewhat special insofar as athletics were [important enough to even be considered sacred](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Olympic_Games). In athletics it is often better to wear less, and so nakedness may have come to appear less plebeian and more elitist. [This article](https://www.ancientworldmagazine.com/articles/heroic-nudity-naked-men-ancient-greek-art/) makes a similar point, but also adds some other aspects.

One common feature of elite lifestyles around the world is that women are not expected to work. For the Middle East, this means they can spend most of their time at home, protected from the sun and dust of the streets. If women *did* venture out of their houses, they would be expected to protect themselves from sun and dust by wearing veils and head scarfs etc. Clothes that are somewhat impractical when you are supposed to do real work in hot weather.

This covering up is not restricted to Islamic countries - farmers working in the fields in Europe used to wear head scarfs until a few decades ago. Female street sweepers in China definitely also tend to cover their hair and faces a lot. The difference to the Middle East is that farming and street sweeping are really lower-class occupations and that upper-class women would not need to protect their hair from getting dusty because they could quite easily avoid dusty conditions altogether.

But also see [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veil) which describes the veil's function in pre-Islamic societies much more in terms of social status rather than in terms of any practical usefulness.

---

That said, a few examples for not-so-modest Islamic art are the [Arabian Nights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Thousand_and_One_Nights), [a statue](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/Hisham%27s_Palace_%28Khirbat_al_Mafjar%29_remains_at_the_Rockefeller_Museum_IMG_7191.JPG) from [Hisham's palace in Jericho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hisham%27s_Palace), or [certain](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Paintings_in_Chehel_Sotun#/media/File:32269-Isfahan-Chehel-Sotoon-Museum_(3446506540).jpg) [frescoes](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Painting_of_Chaharshanbe_Suri_at_Chehel_Sotoun#/media/File:32268-Isfahan-Chehel-Sotoon-Museum_(3445689693).jpg) at the [Chehel Sotun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chehel_Sotoun) palace in Esfahan.

Comment: "In most cultures, nakedness (esp. male nakedness) will be associated with hard work" You're right, that is completely hypothetical and guesswork.

Comment: @Jos examples added.

Comment: I would challenge the idea that nakedness is associated with hard work.  To the contrary, at least in recent to modern times one dons protective clothing when doing most kinds of physical work.  See e.g. overalls https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overalls or remember that the now-ubiquitous blue jeans were originally protective clothing for miners in the California Gold Rush.

Comment: @jamesqf When I grew up, a naked upper body was a very working-class thing. Only common among lorry drivers, construction workers and the like. Except around bodies of water. Ofc. rules about protective equipment on construction sites have become stricter and lorries have become airconditioned, so this is much less common now.

Comment: @Jan: I wouldn't call driving a lorry hard work, and seldom if ever see topless truck drivers in the US.  Likewise with topless construction workers - and I've been a construction worker.  May be geographic differences: what would be ok in Britain (which I'm assuming from your use of "lorry") would set you up for serious sunburn in much of the western US.

Comment: @jamesqf: Driving a truck is not very hard as long as nothing breaks and you don't have to load/unload ;) Topless construction worker: https://www.maz-online.de/Lokales/Ostprignitz-Ruppin/Der-hellste-Arbeitsplatz Two or three topless guys next to at least one truck (looks like IFA W-50): https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0a/Bundesarchiv_Bild_183-M0712-0004%2C_Ernte%2C_Verpflegung_auf_dem_Feld.jpg

Comment: @Jan: Your first link is unviewable, as the content is blocked by what appears to be a "turn off your ad blocker" popup in German.  (Which I don't read, anyway.)  Your second lacks any context.

Comment: @jamesqf: You can find a few similar pictures when doing an image search for Dachdecker + Sommer (roofer + summer) and LPG + Ernte (kolkhoz + harvest). The context for the image is here: https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bundesarchiv_Bild_183-M0712-0004,_Ernte,_Verpflegung_auf_dem_Feld.jpg These are combine drivers and possibly a truck driver among them. There is another picture from the same village and month with a topless guy actually almost in his truck: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bundesarchiv_Bild_183-M0712-0005,_KAP_G%C3%B6rzig-Gr%C3%B6bzig-W%C3%B6rbzig,_Ernte.jpg

Comment: @jamesfq, lorry driving has not been physically hard work for some decades, as all main controls now have either air or hydraulic assistance (if they are still controls which involve mechanical linkages) or are purely electrical. But lorry driving was originally very hard work indeed, which is why an older stereotype of drivers is of large and very powerfully built men.